# Is possible change css inline <div id="feedback_xxx"

Tags: html, css, inline-editing

is possible change CSS inline `<div id="feedback_xxx"` to CSS? id is variable

Example:

```
<div id="feedback_0GJ0FTyrmDV0Nl50j"
<div id="feedback_0GJ0FTyrmDV0Nl55L"
<div id="feedback_00J0FTyrmDV0Nl50j"
```

Rules CSS?

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that in css.

But you can do that using `jquery`

here's how to assign id programmatically

```
$('#oldID').attr("id","#newID");
```

Answer (score 0):

give them a common className

```
<div id="doesnt_matter_what" class="feedback-container">...</div>
<div id="doesnt_matter_what-else" class="feedback-container">...</div>
<div id="doesnt_matter_what-different" class="feedback-container">...</div>
```

css:

```
.feadeback-container{
  /* your styles here */
}
```